# C# Collision Detection Optimization

Tags: c#

My collision detection between two rectangles or a point and rectangle had dozens of if statements and a lot of repetitive code. Today I redid it and I am wondering if the way I did it is an efficient way and if there is a way to optimize it more?

```
class CollisionDetector
{
    public bool CheckForCollision(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
    {
        if ((CheckForCollision(rect1, rect2.Top, rect2.Left)) ||
            (CheckForCollision(rect1, rect2.Top, rect2.Left)) ||
            (CheckForCollision(rect1, rect2.Top, rect2.Left)) ||
            (CheckForCollision(rect1, rect2.Top, rect2.Left)))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckForCollision(Rectangle rect, Point point)
    {
        return CheckForCollision(rect, point.X, point.Y);
    }

    public bool CheckForCollision(Rectangle rect, int x, int y)
    {
        if (x > rect.Left && x < rect.Right && y > rect.Top && y < rect.Bottom)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For improving working code, take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - but be sure to read their help centre first to make sure you're on-topic.

Comment: All four conditions in your if statement are identical.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to check if two non-empty linear ranges overlap:

```
public bool Overlaps(int b1, int e1, int b2, int e2) {
  return b1 <= e2 && b2 <= e1;
}
```

This is perhaps easier to see if the condition is negated:

```
public bool Overlaps(int b1, int e1, int b2, int e2) {
  return !(b1 > e2 || b2 > e1);
}
```

In other words, the only way the two ranges [b1, e1] and [b2, e2] *don't* overlap is if the first range is entirely before or entirely after the second range.

Now, it's easy to extend this to rectangles: two rectangles overlap if and only if their horizontal ranges overlap and their vertical ranges also overlap. So you only need four conditionals in total, rather than the sixteen that the corrected version of your approach would take.

Answer (score 0):

First start by asking is the code correct?
The answer is no, and it is easy to point to errors:
1) you check the same point all 4 times (top left)
2) the case of a rectangle inside a rectangle is not covered

Now there is no point of referring to the current code for efficiency is there?